# Share pre-fork blockchain between Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I run full-node of Bitcoin on Bitcoin Core software. Now I want to also run full-node of Bitcoin Cash. I googled around and found three softwares which support Bitcoin Cash: Bitcoin ABC, Bitcoin Unlimited and Bitcoin XT. Now I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to share pre-fork blockchain between Bitcoin Core and one of Bicoin Cash clients?
2. All of Bitcoin Cash clients use same registry keys as Bitcoin Core?